# why I can't see filename of header tag when we inspect elements

Tags: css, web, frontend

when we inspect elements in css header tag why we can't see origin of file, if I I click on

tag I can see source of file i.e. tut16.html?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the elements with your browser `F12`, you will get each element with its filename (marked in red).

Here is an example of where to look to get the filename when you inspect `css`:

---

[image: inspect css elements and get their path]

This screenshot is taken with the Firefox browser. If you hover your mouse over the link in your console, you will also get the path.